# invert 2 items in a list Python

Tags: python

I'm building a Formula1 race simulator in python and I'm trying to make a overtake function, basically, i've all the drivers stored in a list and once one of the drivers surpasses the other I need to invert their position in the list

```
['hamilton','vertsappen','perez','sainz']
['hamilton','perez','verstappen','sainz']
```

is there any way to do so?

since now I have tried to store the original positions in a temporary variable but I keep finding myself with duplicates in the list

original temporary variables

```
overtaken temp = Valteri Bottas
overtaker temp = Nicholas Latifi
```

after the inverting

```
overtaken temp = Valteri Bottas
overtaker temp = Valteri Bottas
```

Comment: can you mutate the existing list or do you need to create a new one and keep the original position as-is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lazy way to do it.

```
a = ['hamilton','vertsappen','perez','sainz']

a.remove('vertsappen')

a.insert(2, 'vertsappen')

print(a)

#['hamilton','perez','verstappen','sainz']
```

Answer (score 0):

i solved the problem, it was much easier then i thought:

```
grid[0], grid[1] = grid[1] = grid[0]
```

Comment: There's a typo. It should be `grid[1], grid[0]`